# Content-Security-Policy, Safari and script hash

Tags: html

I'm having issues setting csp policy. I'm using hash to allow certain inline script blocks (eg. <script> //js </script>). It works in Chrome and almost flawlessly in Firefox, but Safari not so much :(

Test case:

```http
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'sha256-0Qss1xEkcb2As4MFFFPMYEg1OWydEkMuiEBUHWtwWAw='

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <script>document.write('js works');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The other way to do it is with 'nonce-...', but result is the same.

Am I doing something wrong or is csp hash/nonce just unsupported in Safari?

Comment: Since Safari does not implement CSP2 yet, it appears to be safe to add unsafe-inline to the list, CSP2 browser will ignore it if there is at least one hash-source on the list https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directive-script-src

Comment: Safari10 has implemented CSP 2 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html